# Using Firebase Analytics with a named FirebaseApp

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Firebase Analytics with my application. I've linked the proper frameworks and installed the `plist` that Google provides.

The following code works fine and I can see `my_event` showing up in the Firebase Debug View:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Analytics.logEvent("my_event")
```

This code does not work:

```
let plist = Bundle.main.url(
  forResource: "GoogleService-Info", 
  withExtension: "plist"
)!
let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: plist.path)!
FirebaseApp.configure(name: "customName", options)
Analytics.logEvent("my_event")
```

In the console I see the message

```
2020-03-26 15:27:08.969113-0700 dmpremier[83834:51654982] 6.21.0 - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS025018] Event not logged. Call +[FIRApp configure]: my_event
```

So I am assuming that Analytics only works if you configure a default Firebase app.  Is this correct, or is there something else I can do to link analytics to a named app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytics only works with the default Firebase app.  This is also true for Cloud Messaging, and perhaps other products that are deeply tied to analytics.

You can tell by looking at the APIs - if they don't accept a FirebaseApp instance to work with, then they only work with the default.